# Having a hard time linking my css and JS files on a Boostrap to WP conversion

Tags: css

Trying to link my css and JS files on local host to convert Boostrap theme to WP.

This is the theme:

https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-creative/

Here is the code:

http://pastebin.com/BbXbxL8T

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked if weather scripts are added? If not please check by viewing the page source.

Adding theme style procedure is wrong. Use the procedure below:

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'base-style', get_stylesheet_uri() );
```